# Is it gerund or present participle and how?

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, present-participles

I saw a running girl coming towards us. What is coming in it? I believe present participle but can you explain?

Comment: I saw a girl running towards us. is what we would say here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerunds are substantives, and they typically fill the kinds of roles that nouns also typically fill.  Participles are modifiers, and they typically fill the kinds of roles that adjectives and adverbs also typically fill.

In your model, "coming toward us" modifies "a running girl".

Under a traditional analysis, "I" is the subject, "saw" is a complexly transitive verb, "a running girl" is the direct object, and "coming toward us" is the object complement.

If the complement were substantive, then it would share its referent with the direct object.  In this model it doesn't, so it isn't a gerund.  It's a participle, playing a role typically played by adjectives.

Comment: Thank you gary 

Answer (score 1):

The verb "see" is a *verb of perception*. It is the most common verb of perception. Other similar verbs are "hear", "feel" and "notice".

There are two structures.  In this analysis I won't try to distinguish between gerunds and participles. To me they are the same.

> [Subject] "see" [Object] [bare infinitive]

> I saw Jack eat a hotdog.

or

> [Subject] "see" [Object] [gerund/participle]

> I saw Jack eating a hotdog.

The first form suggests that you saw the whole action, from the first bite to the last.  The second suggests you first saw the man while he was eating, but the difference is only one of nuance and there is flexibility.

In your case, the phrase "coming towards us" is a gerund/participle.  As I've said, in modern English there isn't really any difference.

I realise that I am "unanswering the question".  A traditional grammar would say that a gerund functions as a noun, and a participle functions as an adjective or adverb.  But in the case of verbs of perception, the phrase is not like either a noun nor an adjective. It is part of the particular structure of this special class of verbs. If you study "Old English" (from 1000 years ago) you'll find that this phrase was a participle, but Old English isn't the same as Modern English.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable help

Answer (score 0):

> *I saw a running girl* [*coming towards us*].

Traditional grammar classifies "coming" as a present participle, not as a gerund, but modern grammar simply uses the term 'gerund-participle' for both *ing* forms.

The bracketed subordinate clause is strictly speaking ambiguous between a modifier of "girl" and a catenative complement of "saw".

In the modifier reading, the gerund-participial has a similar meaning to a relative clause, cf. "I saw a running girl [who was coming towards us]".

In the catenative reading, "saw" is a catenative verb with the subordinate clause functioning as its complement. The noun phrase "a running girl" is the syntactic object of "saw" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.